# Melt large list into long format efficiently

Tags: r, list, reshape

I got a large `list` in the following format:

```
example <- list("12908430751", "12908453145", c("12908453145","12908472085","453145472085"), c("12908453145", "12908472085", "453145472085"), "12908453145", c("12908453145", "12908472085", "453145472085"))

example
[[1]]
[1] "12908430751"

[[2]]
[1] "12908453145"

[[3]]
[1] "12908453145"  "12908472085"  "453145472085"

[[4]]
[1] "12908453145"  "12908472085"  "453145472085"

[[5]]
[1] "12908453145"

[[6]]
[1] "12908453145"  "12908472085"  "453145472085"
```

While using `library(reshape2); melt(example)` works for smaller data sets, it takes a very long time for my actual data (~6 million elements). I wonder if there is a more efficient way to realize this.

```
Output
      value     L1
1   12908430751  1
2   12908453145  2
3   12908453145  3
4   12908472085  3
5  453145472085  3
6   12908453145  4
7   12908472085  4
8  453145472085  4
9   12908453145  5
10  12908453145  6
11  12908472085  6
12 453145472085  6
```

I found something similar [Melt data.frame containing list to long format (efficiently)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32198955/melt-data-frame-containing-list-to-long-format-efficiently) but failed to adapt this to my case.

**RESULT**
`example1` with 1 million elements

```
system.time({foo <- unlist(lapply(example1, function(x) length(x)))
result <- data.frame(value = unlist(example1), 
L1 = unlist(sapply(1:length(foo), function(x) rep(x, foo[x]))))})
```

User system elapsed

9.63 0.10 9.73

```
system.time({
df <- structure(list(value = example1 , id = 1:length(example1)), .Names = 
c("value", "L1"), row.names = 1:length(example), class = "data.frame")
result1 <- setDT(df)[, .(value = unlist(value)), by = .(L1)]})
```

User system elapsed

1.25 0.00 1.26

```
system.time({result3 <- tibble(L1 = 1:length(example1), value = example1) %>% unnest()})
```

User system elapsed

5.99 0.00 5.98

```
system.time({ stack(setNames(example1, seq_along(example)))})
```

User system elapsed

1.08 0.00 1.08

Could not get the parallel version to end with a result but might be on my side. Even though I did not define efficiency I go with the fastest approach.

Comment: It's going to be far from the fastest, but `stack(setNames(example, seq_along(example)))` will be an order of magnitude faster than `melt` by my testing.

Comment: Answers here seem to be appropriate and very quick - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31551036/unlisting-columns-by-groups

Comment: And, to me at least, @thelatemail's suggestion is more concise and readable than any of the other solutions posted (including my own)

Comment: agree, if @thelatemail adds his comment as an answer I could accept it

Comment: @user6617454 - done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There probably are faster methods if you dig around, but base R has `stack` which works quite quickly:

```
stack(setNames(example, seq_along(example)))

#         values ind
#1   12908430751   1
#2   12908453145   2
#3   12908453145   3
#4   12908472085   3
#5  453145472085   3
#6   12908453145   4
#7   12908472085   4
#8  453145472085   4
#9   12908453145   5
#10  12908453145   6
#11  12908472085   6
#12 453145472085   6
```

It's internals are basically an `unlist` and then repeating each value of `names(x)`, the corresponding `lengths(x)` times. See `utils:::stack.default` to have a read of the code.

Comment: Probably faster would be `data.frame(values = unlist(example), ind = rep(seq_along(example), lengths(example)))`

Answer (score 0):

You may see an improvement using `parallel` without too much effort

```
library(parallel)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(data.table)  # for rleid

cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())   # automatically detect number of cores
clusterEvalQ(cl, { library(reshape2) })  # need to export package to workers

# Split your data into chunks
nchunks <- 2   # does not need to equal number of cores (can be > # of cores but should be close to number of cores)
chunks <- split(example, cut(seq_along(example), nchunks))
result <- parLapply(cl, chunks, function(i) { melt(i) })
stopCluster(cl)

# combine back into data.frame
df <- Reduce("rbind", result)
answer <- df %>%
        mutate(L1 = rleid(L1))
```

Output

```
          value L1
1   12908430751  1
2   12908453145  2
3   12908453145  3
4   12908472085  3
5  453145472085  3
6   12908453145  4
7   12908472085  4
8  453145472085  4
9   12908453145  5
10  12908453145  6
11  12908472085  6
12 453145472085  6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to use a `tidyverse` approach, how about making a `tibble` which you then `unnest` (I'm not sure how efficient this will be for your use case though):

```r
library(tidyverse)

tibble(L1 = 1:length(example), value = example) %>% unnest()

#> # A tibble: 12 x 2
#>       L1        value
#>    <int>        <chr>
#>  1     1  12908430751
#>  2     2  12908453145
#>  3     3  12908453145
#>  4     3  12908472085
#>  5     3 453145472085
#>  6     4  12908453145
#>  7     4  12908472085
#>  8     4 453145472085
#>  9     5  12908453145
#> 10     6  12908453145
#> 11     6  12908472085
#> 12     6 453145472085
```

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna try this:

```
df <- structure(list(value = example , id = 1:length(example)), .Names = c("value", "L1"), 
            row.names = 1:length(example), class = "data.frame")

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(value = unlist(value)), by = .(L1)]

##     L1        value
##  1:  1  12908430751
##  2:  2  12908453145
##  3:  3  12908453145
##  4:  3  12908472085
##  5:  3 453145472085
##  6:  4  12908453145
##  7:  4  12908472085
##  8:  4 453145472085
##  9:  5  12908453145
## 10:  6  12908453145
## 11:  6  12908472085
## 12:  6 453145472085
```